# How to do a proof by constructing bijections

Tags: proof-writing, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> In this problem, construct a bijection to show the identity. Use the definitions of these quantities, not formulas for them.
>
> For $0≤j≤n$
> $$\binom{n}{j}=\binom{n}{n-j}$$

I know how to prove this by induction, but I have no idea what "construct a bijection" stands for. Could anyone explain this or (better) show me an example? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_proof (did you try googling "construct a bijection" by the way?)

Comment: Apparently they are _defining_ binomial coefficients $\binom nj$ (for $n,j\in\Bbb N$) as the size of some set. Most probably the set of $j$-element subsets of some fixed $n$-element set. Then showing two binomial coefficients equal amounts to showing that two such sets have the same number of elements, and _by definition_ that means there exists a bijection between them. The "construct a bijection" means what it suggests, you have to describe a particular such bijection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the number of ways to arrange $n$ bits, $j$ of which are ones; by definition there are $\binom nj$ ways of doing so. For every such way we can flip the bits to obtain an arrangement of $n$ bits where $n-j$ of them are ones; there are $\binom n{n-j}$ arrangements here. For example:

```
00100110100 <- n=11, j=4
11011001011 <- n=11, j=7
```

This flipping of bits constitutes the bijection. Since every way of arranging the bits is accounted for on both sides of the bijection, this shows that $\binom nj=\binom n{n-j}$.

Answer (score 0):

A bijection is a one-to-one correspondence between sets.   If there is a bijection between two sets they have the same cardinal size (which, for finite sets that is basically: "count of elements").

In this case, $\binom n j$ is the count of ways to select $j$ elements from a set of size $n$.

Meanwhile, $\binom n {n-j}$ is the count of ways to select $n{-}j$ elements from a set of size $n$.

Let us call $N$ the set of $n$ items.   Let $J$ be the set of sets of size $j$ that can be selected from $N$.   Let $K$ be the set of sets of size $n-j$ that can be selected from $N$.

Show that there is a bijection from $J\mapsto K$.   If the sets have the same size then the above counts have the same value.

---

Well, for any set in $J$ there is a single $N$-relative complement of size $n-j$.   ...